# Typescript functions that check for null / undefined

Tags: typescript

I am using `VS Code` and it helps a lot when working with `Typescript` as it tells you when current issues there are without needing to transpile.
I am using `Typescript` with `nodeJS` and it works really well.

The only issue I have is so called "null / undefined checking functions".

See this example:

```js
class User {
   public someProperty: string | undefined;
   // ...

   public get canDoSomething() {
      return this.someProperty != undefined;
   }
}
```

```js
let myUser: User = ...
```

This works nicely:

```js
if (myUser.someProperty != undefined) {
   // at this point myUser.someProperty is type string only (as it cannot be undefined anymore
}
```

However this fails

```js
if (myUser.canDoSomething) {
   // because typescript still thinks that myUser.someProperty is string | undefined and not just string, even though this method checks for that.
}
```

Any idea how I would tell typescript? Because sometimes a method like that is cleaner than keep comparing the properties to undefined itself.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the last `if` statement be: `if (myUser.canDoSomething())`? Without the parentheses, you're not invoking the type guard, just checking whether the function is defined or not. From TypeScript's perspective, `someProperty` can still be `undefined`.

Comment: @MehmetSeckin no, it a class property, not a method, notice the `get`

Comment: Ah, right, my bad. I just realised it was a class property.

Comment: You can use isNullOrUndefined(value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type narrowing works with specific syntactic constructs. `if (obj.prop != undefined)` is one such construct, that will inform the compiler `prop` can't be undefined.

In your case you perform the check in a property. Typescript will not follow the implementation of the getter to see that it performs the null check.

You could use a custom type guard (a method/function with special syntax that informs the compiler of type side effects) :

```
class User {
   public someProperty: string | undefined;

   public canDoSomething() : this is this & { someProperty: string} {
      return this.someProperty != undefined;
   }
}
let myUser: User = new User

if (myUser.canDoSomething()) {
    myUser.someProperty.big()
}
```

I would recommend with sticking with the simpler `if (myUser.someProperty != undefined)` though unless you have a good reason to encapsulate the check.

**Edit**

`this is this & { someProperty: string}` informs the compiler that the type of the object this method was invoked on (`this`) has now changed (`is`) to a new type (the intersection `this & { someProperty: string}`).

`this` in the intersection `this & { someProperty: string}` acts as the type for the current class (called polymorphic `this`) and will be either `User` or any class that derives from user (could have used `User` instead of `this` but it would not have worked on derived classes.

The intersection (`&`) with `{ someProperty: string}` will mean that the type after the check is both whatever class we had before (`this`) and an object with a property `someProperty` of type `string`. Since `User` already had `someProperty` the type of `someProperty` in this intersection will work out to `User['someProperty'] & string = (string | undefined) & string = string`efectively removing `undefined` from the type of `someProperty` in the resulting type.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I added an explanation, hope it makes things a bit more clear

Answer (score -1):

You might want to changed:

`myUser.someProperty != undefined`

To

`typeof myUser.someProperty !== "undefined"`

This will check the typing instead of the value.

Comment: The `myUser.someProperty != undefined` is the one that works ..the second one does not work

Comment: Doesn't really matter. If a variable is of type `undefined`, the variable will have the primitive value `undefined`. Modern browsers will not allow you to overwrite the `undefined`-type. But `propertyName !== undefined` is shorter than the `typeof ...`-check, so I'd prefer that.